# Compiling to a Specific Directory with CodeDom

Tags: c#, compilation

So, I have my program and it does compile directly to the folder that my main EXE is in. Now, I instead want my program to compile to another directory. How can I do this? I have tried Moving it right after it's been Compiled but that doesn't go down too well!

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: My main EXE to output to another directory other than the one it is in by default.